# Potential energy of a system of three charges question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential-energy

> Two point charges are located on the $x$-axis, $q_{1}=-e$ at $x = 0$ and
> $q_{2} = +e$ at $x = a$.
>
> (a) Find the work that must be done by an
> external force to bring a third point charge $q_{3} = +e$ from infinity
> to $x = 2a$.

So i know we have to use (where $k$ is Coulomb's constant)

$$\sum_\ kq_{3}(\frac{q_{1}}{r_{1}} + \frac{q_{2}}{r_{2}} )$$

and the fact that

$$W=-ΔU$$

We know that the initial $U$ is at infinity so $U_{i}$ is zero thus we only have $W=U_{f}$ , the final potential. So we set up our equations

$$W=-(U_{f})=-(ke(\frac{-e}{2a} + \frac{e}{a}))=-(ke\frac{e}{2a})$$

However my book says it is supposed to be positive not negative and doesnt say why. Can anyone please explain why its supposed to be positive?

Comment: Intuitively, without calculating, what sign of the work would you expect from the problem set-up?

Comment: Well the external force needs positive work to move it to 2a. And the amount should be at least equal and opposite to what i have. So i guess i just calculated the work done by the system not the external force?

Comment: Yes, you calculated the work of the electrostatic force which is opposed to the motion.